# Compiling inline text strings in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a simple app in Vue. It's simple enough that I'm not using components.

I store my text strings in a config object so they're easy to change:

```
var config = {
    orderInvalid: "Order {{ order.id }} is invalid"
}
```

In the Vue object I push that data into a generic error variable:

```
if(orderInvalid(orderNumber)){
    this.errorMessage = config.orderInvalid;
}
```

My HTML displays this error:

```
<h1>{{ this.errorMessage }}</h1>
```

The problem is that it isn't parsing the `{{ order.id }}` and displays that string literally. Is there a way around this? I need `{{ order.id }}` to be the actual order id. I was looking at `vue.compile` but it was throwing various errors about missing root elements. I'm guess it is meant for components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `orderInvalid` property of `var config` object is a string which is `"Order {{ order.id }} is invalid"`

So when you use `<h1>{{ this.errorMessage }}</h1>` you just using `<h1>{{ "Order {{ order.id }} is invalid" }}</h1>`

So I recommend using this:

```
var config = {
    orderInvalid: function(orderId){
        return "Order " + orderId + " is invalid"
    } 
}
```

And then

```
if(orderInvalid(orderNumber)){
    this.errorMessage = config.orderInvalid(orderNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ideal solution!

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
orderInvalid: "Order " + order.id + " is invalid"
```

Answer (score 1):

The Handlebars or double mustaches **{{ }}** are used in html to use JS code in html tags. It is primarily syntactical sugar for including JavaScript objects inside your HTML code.

There is no need to use them in JavaScript code itself.  If you write Handlebars inside JavaScript code, then JavaScript interpreter cannot interpret the symbol hence the Error.

In your case the solution should be simply:

```
var config = {
    orderInvalid: "Order " + {{ order.id }} + " is invalid"
}
```

**Updated:**

```
var config = {
    orderInvalid: "Order " + order.id + " is invalid"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not valid JS. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: Oh, totally forgot to remove those mustaches. I have updated the answer. Hope it helps, thanks for showing the Error